# Error listview unbounded height

Tags: android, flutter, app

he escrito un código para entrar en un enlace a través de una imagen de internet que esta en un listview.builder (anteriormente lo he intentado con un container para delimitar el alto y el ancho), pero me da este error:

```
exception has occurred. 
fluttererror (vertical viewport was given unbounded height. 
viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container. 
in this case, a vertical viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand. 
this situation typically happens when a scrollable widget is nested inside another scrollable widget. 
if this widget is always nested in a scrollable widget there is no need to use a viewport because there will always be enough vertical space for the children. 
in this case, consider using a column instead. 
otherwise, consider using the "shrinkwrap" property (or a shrinkwrappingviewport) to size the height of the viewport to the sum of the heights of its children.)
```

el codigo:

Parte 1:

```
ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: 10,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return  Container(
                child:
                  VentanaPrueba(),
              );
```

Parte 2:

```
class VentanaPrueba extends StatefulWidget {
  const VentanaPrueba({super.key});

  @override
  State<VentanaPrueba> createState() => _VentanaPruebaState();
}

class _VentanaPruebaState extends State<VentanaPrueba> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 300,
      width: 400,
      //margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      alignment:Alignment.center,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: const [
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10), child: Text('Nombre del comercio'),),
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10), child: Icon(Icons.open_in_new),),
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: GestureDetector(
              child: Image.network('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/20/Spaghetti_Bolognese_mit_Parmesan_oder_Grana_Padano.jpg/800px-Spaghetti_Bolognese_mit_Parmesan_oder_Grana_Padano.jpg', 
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
              height: 200,),
              //Nos manda a la pagina del comercio/actividad/organismo publico.
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const VistaComercio_Usuario()),
                );
              },
              ...
}
```

La idea es que al clicar en la foto, se pueda acceder a una ventana en la que haya información adicional.

Se agradecería alguna indicación o ayuda

Comment: Es probable que el problema lo tenga el listview, más que los elementos que están dentro. ¿Dónde tienes el listview?

Comment: @Manuel dentro de un column porque quiero un boton flotante a modo de filtro sobre el listview

Comment: Añade expanded sobre el listview en ese caso.

Comment: Me sigue saliendo el mismo error, con lisview, sin el, con container, con expanded, voy a seguir haciendo pruebas a ver como encajo esto